# AtTask getApiKey action returns unsupported action error

Tags: api-key, attask

I'm following the [directions](https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/#API_key) in the AtTask API documentation to get an API key. My user is a system administrator, but the request always returns an error.

Request:

```
GET /attask/api/v4.0/user?action=getApiKey&username=user@company.com&password=********&method=put
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "class": "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException",
        "message": "APIModel V4_0 does not support action getApiKey (USER)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following should work

```
GET /attask/api-unsupported/user?action=getApiKey&username=user@company.com&password=********&method=put
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that now api keys are supported only in the latest (unstable) version of api. Try to pass `unsupported` or `internal` instead `v4.0`. 
That way you will get the latest features of api.